# ant script to compare directories

Tags: ant, build

I have a javascript project with the following structure:

```
root - 
  /docs
  /dist
  /source
  /resources
  /plugins
```

Code is in `source` directory and an `ant` script is executed to generate compressed files in `dist` directory. All the files are in source control.

I want to run a directory diff before running the ant script to make sure the list of files in `source` and `dist` directories are same. If not, stop execution and tell the user to checkin the needed files before running the build.

I am new to ant and am unable to find any documentation to list differences in files list between 2 directories. Appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following. Prints a list of the files to be checked in before failing:

```
<project name="demo" default="build">

    <target name="check">
        <apply executable="echo" failonerror="false" resultproperty="files.found">
            <arg line="missing file:"/>
            <srcfile/>
            <fileset id="srcfiles" dir="source" includes="*.txt">
                <present present="srconly" targetdir="dist"/>
            </fileset>
        </apply>

        <fail message="Files need to be checked in" if="files.found"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="check">
        ..
        ..
        ..
    </target>

</project>
```

Note:

- Tested on Linux. Probably won't work on windows.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That worked like a charm on Windows too.. Your solution gave the idea for me to tweak for my purpose.

Comment: By the way, what is the significance of `<srcfile/>` ?

Comment: @Kiran It's a placeholder for the filename supplied by the fileset. See the ANT manual doco: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html